# How to stop iOS simulator hiding xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to follow some tutorials online. Every time i run the iOS simulator my xcode seems to minimise and focus goes to the simulator on the desktop

Is it possible to stop this and have the simulator load on top of the Xcode window?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus will switch over but Xcode itself doesn't minimise. However, if you're running Xcocde full screen (you have clicked on the <-> arrow in the top right of the screen) then you will switch to a different screen - this is standard behaviour for all maximised apps. Clicking on the green full screen icon in Xcode will make the window take up all available space but without taking a separate screen, which will give the behaviour that you want -- though note this is for 10.9; I seem to recall that clicking the green button on later versions of OSX may automatically trigger the full/separate screen mode.